# Reshaping wide dataframe to long format

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df in the following format:

| name | other_info | revenues_2015 | ebitda_2015 | ebitda_2016 | revenues_2015 | other_2017 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Info1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| B | Info2 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| C | Info3 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |

I would like to change it to long format where I have it structured in the following way:

Name | Info | Year | Metric name | Value

Can you show me how to do that in R?
Since the real dataframe has more than 300 columns, is there a way to automate the creation of the year column?

---

**Data:**

```
structure(list(name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), other_info = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Info1", 
"Info2", "Info3"), class = "factor"), revenues_2015 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "11", "6"), class = "factor"), ebitda_2015 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("12", "2", "7"), class = "factor"), ebitda_2016 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("13", "3", "8"), class = "factor"), revenues_2015 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("14", "4", "9"), class = "factor"), other_2017 = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("10", "15", "5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Yes. You can do that with pivot_longer from the tidyverse package. There‘s a parameter called names_sep where you can specify to split the names at the underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

structure(list(name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), other_info = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Info1", 
"Info2", "Info3"), class = "factor"), revenues_2015 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "11", "6"), class = "factor"), ebitda_2015 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("12", "2", "7"), class = "factor"), ebitda_2016 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("13", "3", "8"), class = "factor"), revenues_2015 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("14", "4", "9"), class = "factor"), other_2017 = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("10", "15", "5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(revenues_2015:other_2017, names_pattern = "(.+)_(\\d{4})", names_to = c("metric", "year"))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: You could also do the shortcut as @deschen suggested `pivot_longer(revenues_2015:other_2017, names_sep = "_", names_to = c("metric", "year"))`, but `names_pattern` is more powerful if you can regex.

Comment: Yes, this works as long as no other '_' are present in the name of the variable

Answer (score 1):

You have two option, you can use the utils package (base-r functions, you do not have to call it using library())  or the melt function from reshape2 package.

With the **function** *reshape()*:

```
 data = structure(list(name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), other_info = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Info1", 
"Info2", "Info3"), class = "factor"), revenues_2015 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "11", "6"), class = "factor"), ebitda_2015 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("12", "2", "7"), class = "factor"), ebitda_2016 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("13", "3", "8"), class = "factor"), revenues_2015 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("14", "4", "9"), class = "factor"), other_2017 = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("10", "15", "5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

LF_data = reshape(data=data, idvar = c("name","other_info"), varying =c("revenues_2015","ebitda_2015","ebitda_2016","revenues_2015","other_2017"), 
    v.names = c("Value"),times=c("revenues_2015","ebitda_2015","ebitda_2016","revenues_2015","other_2017"), direction = "long")
```

Using the **package** reshape2 *melt()* function:

1. First you will need to have a dataframe with the attribute
   stringsAsFactor = False

```
       data=data.frame(structure(list(name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
        ), class = "factor"), other_info = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Info1", 
        "Info2", "Info3"), class = "factor"), revenues_2015 = structure(c(1L, 
        3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "11", "6"), class = "factor"), ebitda_2015 = structure(c(2L, 
        3L, 1L), .Label = c("12", "2", "7"), class = "factor"), ebitda_2016 = structure(c(2L, 
        3L, 1L), .Label = c("13", "3", "8"), class = "factor"), revenues_2015 = structure(c(2L, 
        3L, 1L), .Label = c("14", "4", "9"), class = "factor"), other_2017 = structure(c(3L, 
        1L, 2L), .Label = c("10", "15", "5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -3L)),stringsAsFactors=False)

 2. Then:
```

```
LF_data=reshape2::melt(data,id.vars=c("name","other_info"), mesure.vars=c("revenues_2015","ebitda_2015","ebitda_2016","revenues_2015","other_2017"))
```

**melt** wont let you have a combination of "name","other_info" and "variable" unless they are unique. In your example it would change the second triplets of revenues_2015 to revenues_2015.1

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot

Comment: @PietroFabbro you could use a variable to feed the names and times attributes so you do not have to write all the columns names. Just remember to take out of that variable the names of the columns you want to leave as columns in the long format.

Answer (score 0):

A little too late: Similar to the-mad-statter solution. Slightly different using mutate:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), other_info = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Info1", 
"Info2", "Info3"), class = "factor"), revenues_2015 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "11", "6"), class = "factor"), ebitda_2015 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("12", "2", "7"), class = "factor"), ebitda_2016 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("13", "3", "8"), class = "factor"), revenues_2015 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("14", "4", "9"), class = "factor"), other_2017 = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("10", "15", "5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(revenues_2015:other_2017, names_to = c("Metric name", "Year"),
               names_sep ="_", values_to = "Value") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Year = stringr::str_remove(Year, "\\D")) %>% 
  rename(Name=name, Info = other_info)
```

[image]